# ActiveRecord Loading Relational Table As Enum Instances On Class Load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, enums

I have a relational database table that holds a product lookup.  This table powers multiple systems, only one of which is a Rails app.  In the Rails app, I want to use the product lookup as an ActiveRecord class with instance members with the product code - for example, the key code field is a 4-digit alphanumeric.  It would be nice to be able to refer to instances by the code like this:  ProductCode.01A3.  I don't want to simply declare them in the Rails code, of course, because the DB is the system of record for multiple systems.  Also, how would Ruby react to a non-existent product code?  If ProductCode.ABCD doesn't exist, does it just silently return a nil, and I'd need nil checks everywhere?  And then there's the issue of releasing a new ProductCode into production.  Updating the table would require reloading the class instance variables.

Thoughts?  Can this be done?  Should this be done?  I've searched for a library but maybe my Google-fu isn't that good.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup tables are a great tool to reduce the number of database queries and I often use them in long worker processes. I wouldn't recommend using them in a webapp unless the data is often accessed rarely changes and is expensive to get.

My implementation for you problem would look like this:

```
class ProductCode
  @product_codes = {}
  class << self
    attr_accessor :product_codes
  end

  def self.get(code)
    @product_codes[code.to_s]
  end

  def self.cache_all
    # whatever you do here
    @product_codes = {'01A3' => 42}
  end
end

ProductCodes.cache_all

ProductCodes.get('01A3')
```